# Nested MySQL queries

Tags: mysql, sql, nested

I currently have the following query:

```
select min(nw_lpdTEMP) AS Min_Lkpmp_Temp_C,
  max(nw_lpdPH) AS Max_Lkpmp_PH,
(select format(nw_uvttlflw,7) from tag_history 
  where from_unixtime(floor(unix_timestamp(t_stamp)/60)*60)
  Between '2012-07-01 00:00:00' AND '2012-07-01 23:59:59' order by nw_bpdcl2 limit 1) as Min_GPM, 
  format(min(nw_bpdcl2),7) as Min_Chlorine_Residual,
(select format(nw_uvttlflw,7) from tag_history
  where from_unixtime(floor(unix_timestamp(t_stamp)/60)*60)
  Between '2012-07-01 00:00:00' AND '2012-07-01 23:59:59' order by nw_bpdcl2 desc limit 1) as Max_GPM,
  format(max(nw_bpdcl2),7) as Max_Chlorine_Residual from tag_history 
  where from_unixtime(floor(unix_timestamp(t_stamp)/60)*60) 
  Between '2012-07-01 00:00:00' AND '2012-07-01 23:59:59'
```

and am looking to see if I can add the following query which returns the sum of a gallons per minute flow (nw_uvttlflw) between 24 hours. I can run the (sum query) query that I am trying to add to the above query by itself and it returns exactly what I want. My current problem is trying to nest it with the above query so it returns the sum (nw_uvttlflw) as the last column in the original larger query. (Sorry for my lack of quality formatting for the nested SQL query as I am not the most versed with lengthy queries)

The query I am trying to append is here:

```
select format(sum(nw_uvttlflw),7) as Total_flow from tag_history
where from_unixtime(floor(unix_timestamp(t_stamp)/60)*60) 
Between '2012-07-01 00:00:00' AND '2012-07-01 23:59:59';
```

Your time and effort is greatly appreciated. I have been trying to piece this together for some time an can't get my syntax just right. Thanks

-Mark

Comment: You select everything from the tag_history table? Why are you nesting then?

Comment: I need nested queries because if you look at the larger query it grabs a min from a column and max from another AND then it grabs the Min_Chlorine_Residual and the GPM at the same point in time where the Chlorine_Residual is at its minimum for the day. It also does this for the max hence the need for nested queries. Please see the original query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this what you're looking for?

```
select min(nw_lpdTEMP) AS Min_Lkpmp_Temp_C,
  max(nw_lpdPH) AS Max_Lkpmp_PH,
  (select format(nw_uvttlflw,7) from tag_history 
    where from_unixtime(floor(unix_timestamp(t_stamp)/60)*60)
    Between '2012-07-01 00:00:00' AND '2012-07-01 23:59:59' order by nw_bpdcl2 limit 1) as Min_GPM, 
  format(min(nw_bpdcl2),7) as Min_Chlorine_Residual,
  (select format(nw_uvttlflw,7) from tag_history
    where from_unixtime(floor(unix_timestamp(t_stamp)/60)*60)
    Between '2012-07-01 00:00:00' AND '2012-07-01 23:59:59' order by nw_bpdcl2 desc limit 1) as Max_GPM,
  format(max(nw_bpdcl2),7) as Max_Chlorine_Residual,
  (select format(sum(nw_uvttlflw),7) from tag_history
    where from_unixtime(floor(unix_timestamp(t_stamp)/60)*60) 
    Between '2012-07-01 00:00:00' AND '2012-07-01 23:59:59') as Total_flow
from tag_history 
where from_unixtime(floor(unix_timestamp(t_stamp)/60)*60) 
  Between '2012-07-01 00:00:00' AND '2012-07-01 23:59:59'
```

Comment: Exactly Tim! I hope one day to be on your level. I am still learning nested queries. I am going to study your query to see if I can find my mistake, but if you wouldn't mind would you please elaborate on how to piece together nested queries. I have read through the MySQL documentation and don't quite understand it. If you wouldn't mind would you do a sample template that breaks down how nested queries work? Thanks so much you have no idea how appreciative I am.